# Object memory allocation

Tags: ruby, object, memory-management

I am wondering how memory allocation works in Ruby.

In Ruby, we can open a class definition and add more instance variables/methods. In this case, new objects would require more memory than existing instances. How does it internally track memory allocated to an instance?

For example, we have the following class definition:

```
class MyClass
    def myMethod
        @a = 5
    end
end
```

We created an instance of `MyClass`:

```
m = MyClass.new
m.myMethod
```

At this point, `m` would be allocated some memory. Now, we open the class definition and add another instance variable `b`.

```
class MyClass
    def mySecondMethod
        @b = 5
    end
end
```

This new method `mySecondMethod` and instance variable `b` are also available in the existing instance `m` of `Myclass`.

Calling `mySecondMethod` to instantiate and initialize `b`:

```
m.mySecondMethod
```

How does Ruby internally manage memory? Does it reallocate the memory chunk for instance `m`, or does it maintain some sort of pointers to the newly allocated memory?

Comment: Just one point - `mySecondMethod` will not be available on the instances like `b`, rather inside the class of instances like `b`.

Comment: @ArupRakshit, I do not understand what you mean by, "instances like `b`". Could you please rephrase this? Thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*The answer depends on the actual implementation. Here I assume you are asking about [MRI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_MRI).*

Ruby objects are allocated on the [*heap*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(programming)). There is no concept of the [*stack*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack-based_memory_allocation) when talking about object allocations.

The heap is split up into *pages*, each consisting of 16kb. Each page is carved up into *fixed size* slots which can hold Ruby objects. A page can hold ~408 objects, since each object (which is an [`RVALUE`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/1aebaf735555068fb82c3d1846166b5afc7af10e/gc.c#L330) struct)  occupies 40bytes.

All of this is managed by the VM (ie. [*YARV*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YARV)).

[image: ruby heap layout]
*source: http://timetobleed.com/garbage-collection-slides-from-la-ruby-conference/*

**Regarding your example**, variables just hold *references* to objects, so `m` actually *points* to an allocated `MyClass` object.

The C struct (`RClass`) that backs up `MyClass` internally, contains a pointer to a table with the user-defined  methods like `#mySecondMethod` and a pointer to a table with the names of the instance variables that its objects have.

Each object (which is backed up by [`RObject`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/71430123d3cc7d5b261313213f17787f6e6f384d/include/ruby/ruby.h#L759) since the [`Object`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Object.html) class is the default root of all objects) internally contains a [pointer to the values of its instance variables](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/71430123d3cc7d5b261313213f17787f6e6f384d/include/ruby/ruby.h#L764).

The newly defined `#mySecondMethod` is available because of the dynamic nature of the language and the fact that method lookup happens at runtime.

Comment: @Agis Your answer is very good. I have one query regarding "All of this is managed by the VM (ie. YARV)." this statement. YARV documentation(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YARV) shows that this is added as a part of Ruby in 1.9 version. So in previous version of ruby How heap memory is managed for ruby object?

Answer (score 1):

Your second guess is correct. Ruby objects maintain pointers to heap memory.

Note, however, that in your example, because `mySecondMethod` is never called on your object `m`, that instance variable `@b` is not set/initialized for `m`.

The thing that will probably help you most is, first, to get a little bit more practice using Ruby and understanding how its class and object idioms work. Then, I would suggest looking at some resources like [this very good and recent article](http://samsaffron.com/archive/2013/11/22/demystifying-the-ruby-gc) about the Ruby garbage collector.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I shall go through it. Actually, forgot to call the mySecondMethod in original question. Edited the question to make a call.